# VS Code - Rename symbol too slow for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, rename

I'm having this refactoring issue where I try to rename a function through the option "Rename symbol", but it will take a long time. There's a "progress bar" moving endlessly below the document tab. It is taking around 5 min to do the renaming (also with variable names).

Is this a normal behaviour? I have about 10 python files in the same folder of around ~100 lines. BUT, I have a data folder (belonging to the project) with some 100,000 txt files (which is ignored by git, btw). Are this documents also taken into account? Is there a way to only rename in current file?

VS Code version: 1.25.0
Python extension: 2018.6.0

Thanks, Rafa

Comment: what about search/replace using grepwin on *.py files? I had a poor experience with VS Code / python mode.

Comment: @Jean-François I don't see how search/replace with grep or any other purely textual tool could sensibly work. You simply need to parse code to avoid false positives when renaming.

Comment: depends on what you want to replace. If it's `search_minimum_by_least_square` it will work all right. If it's `min`, then no; but python is so dynamic that a real smart refactoring is very difficult to achieve (unlike for java). A good tool for that is PyCharm that does an honest job given the difficulty of the task.

Comment: I do ctrl+D or ctrl+H/ctrl+shift+H when renaming, if it helps.

Comment: @bluesmonk those shortcuts work extremely well for my purposes! Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I actually came from PyCharm where the rename function worked very well, but for some reason the whole IDE started lagging badly and not  even a clean reinstall helped me with it. So far I'm happy with VS Code - Python. Maybe in a future update the extension will be a bit more optimized.

Answer (score 8):

same problem here, it's apparently due to the Rope library (which is being used to do the refactoring) not fully supporting Python 3.

Here is an issue of people describing similar problems - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/52

**Update**: Using [Jedi](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead of *Microsoft Python Language Server* for intellisense seems to have fixed this problem for me. Just add the following entry to your settings.json file :

```
"python.jediEnabled": true
```

Comment: Does not help me

Comment: says "Unknown configuration setting" for python.jediEnabled. (by other searches) this is replaced with "python.languageServer": "Jedi",... but this also doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

I found `rope` wasn't ignoring the files in my virtual environment that were in my workspace directory. This created understandably slow refactoring performance. I added my virtual environment folder to the `ignored_resources` in the `rope` configuration file `config.py`. Immediately after making the change, refactoring performance greatly improved.

---

### Example

Take the folder structure below.

```
-.venv
-.vscode
--.ropeproject
---config.py
---objectdb
--pythonpackage
---__init__.py
---[other files I want to refactor]
-main.py
```

Assuming `.venv` is the name of your virtual environment, for `rope` to ignore it, you need to include `.venv` in the `ignored_resources` list in the `rope` `config.py` file. Example shown below.

```
def set_prefs(prefs):
    """This function is called before opening the project"""

    # Specify which files and folders to ignore in the project.
    # Changes to ignored resources are not added to the history and
    # VCSs.  Also they are not returned in `Project.get_files()`.
    # Note that ``?`` and ``*`` match all characters but slashes.
    # '*.pyc': matches 'test.pyc' and 'pkg/test.pyc'
    # 'mod*.pyc': matches 'test/mod1.pyc' but not 'mod/1.pyc'
    # '.svn': matches 'pkg/.svn' and all of its children
    # 'build/*.o': matches 'build/lib.o' but not 'build/sub/lib.o'
    # 'build//*.o': matches 'build/lib.o' and 'build/sub/lib.o'
    prefs['ignored_resources'] = ['*.pyc', '*~', '.ropeproject',
                                  '.hg', '.svn', '_svn', '.git', '.tox', '.venv']
```

---